# How to find $a$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

that $f:\mathbb R \longmapsto \mathbb R $ is contunuous and $1-$periodique .

> Determine the set $a\in \mathbb R $ where $I=\displaystyle \int_1^{\infty}\frac{a-f(x)}{x}dx$  is convergent and Same question when $J=\displaystyle\int_1^{\infty}\frac{a-f(x)}{x^2}dx $ is convergent.

about the first question if we put $f(x)=a $ we find $I$ is convergent and also about the second question we have $\lim_{x \to \infty }x^2 \left(\frac{a-f(x)}{x^2}\right)=1 \implies f(x) \sim (a-1)   $   on neighborhood   $+\infty$  we can say $ J$ is convergent if $ a=f(x)+1 $ but this is not the general solution . So is there any help in calculating $a$ so that $ I$ and $J$  are convergent?

Comment: Hint: can there be more than 1 such $a$ for the $\frac{}{x}$ case? Also, you can't put $a = f(x)$ since $a$ is a constant, not dependent on $x$.

Comment: $I$ will be problematical unless $a-f(x) \to 0$.